# Header bidding to OpenRTB interface

Tags: prebid.js, advertisement-server, header-bidding

We are a ad-tech demand side platform (DSP). Our bidder receives and responds to OpenRTB bid requests from Exchanges/SSPs (sell side platforms). We are looking to enable our bidder for header bidding via prebid.js or similar platform. We are new to header bidding. What are the steps to enable our bidder for header bidding? Is there a open source way to convert prebid.js requests to OpenRTB bid requests?

Comment: hi Sampras, did you find a solution? I'm in a similar situation..

Answer (score 0):

For enabling `header bidding` you'll have to check `OpenRTB3.0` protocol and update your platform to support the same.